# NSDocument-based app window position

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsdocument

My Xcode NSDocument-based app contains a floating panel. On each launch of the app the default doc window and panel appear in their previous locations on the screen. However, if I save a document and quit the app then double click the saved file, the document window is positioned at the same origin as the panel.

Turning off cascading gets around the problem but of course I lose cascading.

A minimum Xcode example showing the issue can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/118ve30ephlw3lf/DocBasedApp2.zip?dl=0).

1. Run the example project.
2. Do a File/Save.
3. Quit the app.   << important
4. Double click the saved file.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So which behavior do you want? Do you want it to appear where it was left before app termination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it had something to do with document windows cascading from the panel. Adding this to the panel controller seems to have fixed it

`- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [self setShouldCascadeWindows:NO];
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the state of your window before the app terminates try this:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    // If you want to save your window position
    // you can use  [window saveFrameUsingName:@"someWindowName"];
    //
    // then use [window setFrameAutosaveName:@"someWindowName"]; at the app launch.

    return NSTerminateNow;
}
```

Comment: I have Autosave name set in the nib, so thought that was same thing.

Comment: This is a multi-document project (sorry, should have mentioned that), so not sure how to implement the above. Anyhow, after many attempts to get around this issue, looks like I've stumbled upon a solution (see next answer).